# react-native-swiper in android screen rotate from potrait to landscape, the scroll is not rerender

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, react-native-swiper

### react-native-swiper  issue

1. swiper width and height are resized after screen rotation(using Dimensions.get('window').width, and height,
2. but the scroll is not Re_render, it shows the portions of previous slide along with active slide

   ```
         <Swiper width={screenData.width} height={screenData.height}>
       <View style={[styles.slide, {backgroundColor: '#fa931d'}]}>
         <View level={10}>
           <Text style={styles.text}>Page 1</Text>
         </View>
       </View>
       <View style={[styles.slide, {backgroundColor: '#a4b602'}]}>
         <View level={-10}>
           <Text style={styles.text}>Page 2</Text>
         </View>
       </View>
       <View style={[styles.slide, {backgroundColor: '#fa931d'}]}>
         <View level={8}>
           <Text style={styles.text}>Page 3</Text>
         </View>
       </View>
       <View style={[styles.slide, {backgroundColor: '#a4b602'}]}>
         <View level={5}>
           <Text style={styles.text}>Page 4</Text>
         </View>
       </View>
     </Swiper>
   ```

Comment: Same issue for me too